# How to extend VS Code Color Theme with Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I know how to create a new theme, but is there any way to extend the default light or dark theme with my additional textMate rules and colors to format theme, in my extension?

I know I can use the extension textMate rules that will be formatted accordingly by the theme, but If I create additional rules those wont be formatted.

How do I add additional token color for those rules?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, extending existing themes is not possible, so you have two options:

1. Create a new theme that includes the default themes and adds your customizations. Your users will have to select this theme themselves.
2. You can try to provide some default settings for `workbench.colorCustomizations` and/or `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` in your package.json. those settings are described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customize-a-color-theme). If that doesn't work, you could add a command that would explicitly set the values in a users settings file.